# transparent window when using gnome-shell and communitheme on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, themes, gnome-shell, system-monitor

I have installed communitheme in gnome-shell. It gives smoother and faster experience. However, I am facing the following issue with System Monitor window. The window is completely transparent.

[image]

is there any way to solve this in this theme?

Comment: The same here! also happend to the calulator app

Comment: filled a bug report here https://github.com/ubuntu/gnome-shell-communitheme/issues/162

Comment: This is in gnome-shell tag added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is already fixed and should land in the stable channel soon:
https://github.com/ubuntu/gtk-communitheme/issues/325

Thanks for reporting, best regards

Comment: Updating my snap didn't solve the problem for me. However, reinstalling the affected snap packages as [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029890/transparent-system-monitor-ubuntu-18-04/1122739#1122739) answer suggests worked

Answer (score 1):

This happens with the calculator and other default apps as well. Default apps are installed in 18.04 through "snap", a new cross-OS package manager. Snap will be much better than APT one day, but right now it's in the beginning stages and experiencing growing pains.

One of these growing pains is that it "themes" each application differently than it has in the past, and some of the new "theming" hasn't had the kinks worked out yet.

Luckily, the workaround is very very easy. **Just uninstall with snap and reinstall with APT.**

```
sudo snap remove gnome-system-monitor
sudo apt install gnome-system-monitor
```

You might want to do this with gnome-calculator, too. I'm still looking for other applications that have this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This might help someone in 2020. `sudo snap refresh` worked for me. You can try it too. It refreshed all the system apps including the core.

```
2020-01-17T00:02:42+05:00 INFO Waiting for restart...
gnome-system-monitor 3.32.1-3-g0ea89b4922 from Canonical✓ refreshed
gtk-common-themes 0.1-28-g1503258 from Canonical✓ refreshed
gnome-calculator 3.34.1+git1.d34dc842 from Canonical✓ refreshed
core 16-2.42.5 from Canonical✓ refreshed
gnome-logs 3.34.0 from Canonical✓ refreshed
core18 20200113 from Canonical✓ refreshed
gnome-3-28-1804 3.28.0-16-g27c9498.27c9498 from Canonical✓ refreshed
gnome-characters v3.32.1+git3.b9120df from Canonical✓ refreshed
```

All of the apps returned to their normal appearance on Ubuntu 18.04.03 as they are used to be in .deb format.