# Transparent System Monitor Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: gnome, system-monitor

I just installed Ubuntu 18.04 and the System Monitor app shows transparent and I have to put it on a dark background to actually see the info. ALso the window does not have borders.

[image: This is a screenshot, I can't embed it]

What can it be? I installed the communitytheme but it seems like that is not the problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This happens with the calculator and other default apps as well. Default apps are installed in 18.04 through "snap", a new cross-OS package manager. Snap will be much better than APT one day, but right now it's in the beginning stages and experiencing growing pains.

One of these growing pains is that it "themes" each application differently than it has in the past, and some of the new "theming" hasn't had the kinks worked out yet.

Luckily, the workaround is very very easy. **Just uninstall with snap and reinstall with APT.**

```
sudo snap remove gnome-system-monitor
sudo apt install gnome-system-monitor
```

You might want to do this with gnome-calculator, too. I'm still looking for other applications that have this issue.

Comment: Did not fix it for me.I'm on gnome-session-flashback, upgraded from Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: The Ambiance theme has those transparency problems.
I'm on gnome-session-flashback, upgraded from Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: It also fixed my issue of getting gnome-system-monitor use Advaita theme, instead of the current one. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This workaround is perfect. Also applicable to gnome-logs app:

```
sudo snap remove gnome-logs
sudo apt-get install gnome-logs
```

Answer (score 1):

you can re-install the snap apps like:

```
snap remove gnome-calculator gnome-system-monitor gnome-characters gnome-logs
snap install gnome-calculator gnome-system-monitor gnome-characters gnome-logs
```

The issue is reported [here](https://github.com/ubuntu/yaru/issues/1212) and closed!

You can get the list of installed snap apps by:
`snap list`

Comment: Updating snap didn't solve the problem for me. I had to manually re-install like this answer suggests and it worked.