# How to change skype default browser

Tags: 18.04, skype, default-browser

I use **Ubuntu 18.04** and I have the following problem.

When I try to open links via **Skype** it opens **Mozilla firefox** also I have set **google chrome** as my default browser.

I tried to find something in skype settings but I found nothing related to the application default browser

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Installing packages from the Ubuntu software center using `snap` have some issues.

> "snap", a new cross-OS package manager. Snap will be much better than APT one day, but right now it's in the beginning stages and experiencing growing pains.

I removed `skype` from the software center and I downloaded the `.deb` file from [Official Skype website](https://www.skype.com/en/get-skype/).

Then I installed it using `dpkg` which solved the problem.

Note: [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1033702/573344) inspired me.

Comment: This has been driving me mad for a while now. Overall the `snap` technology is quite bad. I really don't like it and it doesn't work as well as it should be. AppImage is far better at this and "package" size is considerably lower.

Comment: Open a terminal and write `snap remove skype` to remove it.

Comment: `snap` does exactly what I need.
Snap is a barrier for software that I don't like (Skype) to protect some pieces of my data on system. In this way it is much better than granting everything but it comes with costs.

Answer (score 9):

For me, the following command immediately fixed the issue:

```
ln -s ~/.config/mimeapps.list ~/snap/skype/common/.config/mimeapps.list
```

Comment: i kneel before you

Comment: please, don't xD

Answer (score 6):

To make it work with snap do the following:

1. **Quit skype**
2. `ln -s ~/.config/mimeapps.list ~/snap/skype/common/.config/mimeapps.list`
3. `rm -rf ~/snap/skype/common/.config/google-chrome`
4. `sudo ln -s ~/.config/google-chrome ~/snap/skype/common/.config/`

Answer (score 3):

I resolved the problem following below steps.

1. Uninstall Firefox and open any link in Skype (agree with the alert)
2. Delete (rename) ~ `/snap/skype/common/.config/google-chrome`
3. ```
   sudo ln -s /home/user/.config/google-chrome /home/user/snap/skype/common/.config/
   ```