# Skype doesn't work Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, skype

I have installed skype with the following command:
sudo snap install skype --classic
the problem is when I want to open it, it doesn't work and automatically sign off. Even this happen writting skype on the terminal.

Comment: Can you try Uninstalling Skype by `sudo apt purge skypeforlinux && sudo apt-get autoremove` and then Open Ubuntu Software Center and find Skype, then install?

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove your snap installation using this command

```
sudo snap remove skype
```

then download the `.deb` file from [Official Skype website](https://www.skype.com/en/get-skype/).

Then install it using `dpkg` for ex:

```
dpkg -i /path-to-/deb-file.deb
```

Note: check [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1038335/573344) for more information about snap.